# Using Transifex with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, resources, translation, quotes

I'm trying to make a powershell script to set up Transifex for my project and I keep getting the same errors when I try to run:

```
& tx "set --source -r myproject.auth-resx_myproject -l ""en"" ""C:\MyProjectDir\ResourceFile.resx"""
```

The error is:

```
    tx.exe : tx: Command set --source -r myproject.auth-resx_myproject -l en C:\MyProjectDir\ResourceFile.resx not found
    At line:1 char:2
    + & <<<<  tx "set --source -r myproject.auth-resx_myproject -l ""en"" ""C:\MyProjectDir\ResourceFile.resx""" 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (tx: Command set....resx not found:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

It looks like some characters are not escaped correctly since running the script without the execute operator and quotes work.

```
tx set --source -r myproject.auth-resx_myproject -l "en" "C:\MyProjectDir\ResourceFile.resx"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This begs the question why you're trying with `&` in the first place. But anyway, your problem is your argument list. You don't need to quote it. Actually, you mustn't quote it unless you want to pass it as a single argument to the command. Which you obviously don't, given the line you showed as working.

The working line needs no quotes either in this case, by the way.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was indeed the operator '&'. I'm now using 'iex' to execute my script and it works like a charm!

Comment: Did you read what I wrote at all? `Invoke-Expression` is never an answer to this, though.